# I am unable to add new template type.Error when adding new mediator

Tags: templating

I am getting error when i am trying to add new Mediator.I did following changes in Tridion.ContentManager.config:

```
<section name="mustache.mediator" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache.Configuration.MustacheMediatorConfigurationSection, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=063be528da549efd" />

<add id="10" name="MustacheTemplate" mimeType="text/x-tcm-nustache" hasBinaryContent="false" contentHandler="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache.MustacheContentHandler, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=063be528da549efd">                            
        <webDavFileExtensions>
          <add itemType="TemplateBuildingBlock" fileExtension="nustache" />
        </webDavFileExtensions>
      </add>
    </templateTypes>

 <mediator matchMIMEType="text/x-tcm-nustache" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache" assemblyPath="C:\Mustache\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache.dll" />
```

I uploaded dll into GAC also.
i am getting "object reference not found error".
Please help me for the same.

Comment: It won't be the cause of your problem, but have you noticed that sometimes you say mustache and sometimes nustache?

Comment: Using Nustache, but forgot to put the Nustache dll in the GAC, perhaps? On a side note, you can save troubles and pains by utilizing Nustache (or any other .NET templating libraries) using XView http://xview.codeplex.com

Comment: Check the Tridion event log. Expect to see an error event with a stack trace which provides more insight in where the exception occurs.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response                                                                Issue got resolve as i missed class name to be add in <Mediator section                      <mediator matchMIMEType="text/html" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache.MustacheMediator" assemblyPath="C:\Mustache\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Mustache.dll" />